# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed -- matrix subtract

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, subtraction

*I have to following matrices with parameters:-*

```
cv::Mat fFuncv--> size of fFunc [924440 x 10] and depth 5 

cv::Mat Ones -->size of Ones [924440 x 1] and depth 5

cv::Mat cFuncv-->size of cFunc [1 x 10] and depth 5
```

*when I do:-*

**d = fFunc - Ones * cFunc;**

*I got the following error message*

OpenCV Error:

> Assertion failed (a_size.width == len) in gemm, file D:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\matmul.cpp, line 1537
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     what():  D:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\matmul.cpp:1537: error: (-215) a_size.width == len in function gemm

*if I perform another substract method, like*

**cv::subtract(fFunc,Ones*cFunc,d);**

OpenCV Error:

> Assertion failed (type2 == CV_64F && (sz2.height == 1 || sz2.height == 4)) in arithm_op, file D:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp, line 661
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     what():  D:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:661: error: (-215) type2 == CV_64F && (sz2.height == 1 || sz2.height == 4) in function arithm_op

Can you please help me what the error messages are meaning? What do I wrong?

Comment: there is a typo in the second line of your code. It should be cv::Mat. Maybe thats causing the error.

Comment: @MarKS yep it was just here, that is correct in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe size is `[Width,Height]`, which is `[num_cols,num_rows]` so you can't multiply a
`Ones * cFunc`, but rather `cFunc * Ones`.